# Open Nebula / Eucalyptus / Xen Cloud Platform

Tags: cloud-computing

I am trying to setup a Private Cloud( with features of Amazon EC2 like EIP, EBS and Load Balancing with Multiple Clusters ( with ability to move Clusters/VMs without downtime)

Please share your thoughts

Thanks

Comment: You appear to know the right words, but it's impossible to answer such a general question on a Q&A site. Is there anything specific you'd like to know?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenStack Compute](http://openstack.org/projects/compute/) is an open source "datacenter operating system" containing code from The Rackspace Cloud, NASA Nebula, and others with [a lot of industry partners](http://openstack.org/community/).  You  may want to familiarize yourself with it.